# How to skip multiple test cases in pytest framework?

Tags: python, pytest

I currently have around 100 test cases in my test folder and want to skip 25 of them. Is there any way that I can add a mass skip marker instead of adding individual skip markers to each test?

Comment: No, won't be possible. How would those 25 be identified in the first place?

Comment: @DevangSanghani yes it is possible, but can OP clarify what is the identifying feature among these tests?

Comment: These tests all have "global_locking" in their test name. Instead of individually adding skip marker can i mention these test cases in a file and add only 1 skip marker to them all?

Comment: You can then skip with `pytest -k "not global_locking" filename_test.py`